# How to access mysql V8 on windows V10 with perl?

Tags: mysql, perl, strawberry-perl

I'm mystified that this is so difficult.

(1) With activate state perl v5.26.3 I use ppm.bat and search for mysql and DBD-mysql is missing. As per https://code.activestate.com/ppm/DBD-mysql/ I try

```
ppm install DBD-mysql
```

I get:

```
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides DBD-mysql
```

(2) With the same activestate perl's ppm.bat I see mysqlPP and this does not work with MySQL V8 either:

```
perl -MDBI -e '$cat=$ENV{"MYSQLDATABASECATALOG"}; $svr=$ENV{"MYSQLHOST"}; $user=$ENV{"DATABASEUSER"}; $pass=$ENV{"DATABASECATALOGPASSWORD"}; my $dbh=DBI->connect("dbi:mysqlPP:database=$cat;host=$svr",$user,$pass,{ RaiseError => 1 }) or die "Cannot connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr"; my $q=$ARGV[0]; my $sth=$dbh->prepare($q) or die "Cannot prepare statement: $DBI::errstr"; $sth->execute(); ... $sth->finish(); $dbh->disconnect;'  "<query goes here>"

DBI connect('database=sqlpocket;host=localhost','sqlpocket',...) failed: #08004Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client at C:/Perl64/site/lib/DBD/mysqlPP.pm line 116.
```

(3) Strawberry perl is suppose to have DBD for mysql already installed and that does not work either:

```
perl -MDBI -e '$cat=$ENV{"MYSQLDATABASECATALOG"}; $svr=$ENV{"MYSQLHOST"}; $user=$ENV{"DATABASEUSER"}; $pass=$ENV{"DATABASECATALOGPASSWORD"}; my $dbh=DBI->connect("dbi:mysql:dbname=$cat",$user,$pass,{ RaiseError => 1 }) or die "Cannot connect to $data_source: $DBI::errstr"; my $q=$ARGV[0]; my $sth=$dbh->prepare($q) or die "Cannot prepare statement: $DBI::errstr"; $sth->execute(); ... $sth->finish(); $dbh->disconnect;'  "<sql query goes here>"
```

I get

```
install_driver(mysql) failed: Can't load 'C:/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.xs.dll' for module DBD::mysql: load_file:The specified module could not be found at C:/Users/2207458/Documents/AppBin/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/perl/lib/DynaLoader.pm line 193.
Perhaps a required shared library or dll isn't installed where expected.
```

This is odd because "C:/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.xs.dll" exists and is accessible.

30 Aug 2019 Update:

I'm sorry, I was trying to be less verbose and got sloppy: I removed the "Users/2207458/Documents/AppBin" from the above file name (but I was not consistent). So C:/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.xs.dll was really c:/Users/2207458/Documents/AppBin/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.xs.dll.

PERL5LIB has never been defined. Does it need to be?

Comment: I understand you tried multiple perl installations, that might possibly have messed up things. First thing to check: Is "C:/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/perl/vendor/lib" actually in @INC (PERL5LIB in the environment)?

Comment: I took specific care are to avoid that possibility. Since Strawberry perl gives me the option of avoiding the windows installer in favor of a zip file, I used the zip in my custom directory. ActiveState uses a windows installer to install to c:\perl64 by default.

Comment: Even more so important you make sure `PERL5LIB` points to the correct paths. Did you do that?

Comment: I do $SBPERLBIN/perl -e "print qq(@INC)" and the paths look correct for strawberry perl. I have .../perl/site/lib and .../perl/vender/lib and .../perl/lib. I confirmed that they all exist.

Comment: I use the same command for ActiveState perl and @INC contains .../site/lib and .../lib and these directories exist.

Comment: After google searching I still need help with PERL5LIB. Is this an environment variable? I have not defined it. What should it be defined to be?

Comment: Yes, it lives in the environment, just like PATH and points to where Perl is looking for modules. But I read the question again, and it looks like your are calling the wrong Perl. See, It's looking for modules in `C:/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1/...`, but the code that is doing that is located in `C:/Users/2207458/Documents/AppBin/perlstrawberry/5.30.0.1`. That seems very fishy.

Answer (score 1):

[The answer for windows (and apparently linux) is here: Lefred's Blog](https://lefred.be/content/perl-mysql-8-0/)

I issued this command and reset the password:

```
alter user 'fred' identified   with 'mysql_native_password' by 'mysecurepasswd';
```

This worked for me using ActiveState Perl v5.4 and mysql 8.0.17-winx64.

Apparently this is a security compromise because we are using an older plugin to compare passwords?